# IExplore error reading asp constant into vbs file

Tags: variables, asp-classic, vbscript, include

I have an asp file with a lot of constants (`constants.inc`).
Into asp page:

```
<!-- #Include file="../../constants.INC" -->

....

<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript" src="../scripts/scrmot.vbs"></script>

....
```

Into scrmot.vbs I want to do next:

```
Function validChars
  Dim carval
  carval = <%=scarVal%> 'scarVal is a constant defined in constants.INC
  ....
End Function
```

but that crashes! The entire .vbs file doesn't charge because that instruction get error.
How can assign the constant asp `scarVal` to a vbscript variable `carval`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that like this since .vbs files are not rendered by the ASP engine.

What you can do is pass all the constants you need to client side by having such code in your .asp page itself:

```
<script language="vbscript" type="text/vbscript">
    Const scarVal = "<%=scarVal%>"
</script>
```

And in the function use the client side constant:

```
Function validChars
    Dim carval
    carval = scarVal
    ....
End Function
```

Comment: scarVal is getting an empty string. I made the entire routine in vbs